# having trouble filtering, boolean issue

Tags: json, database, mongodb, boolean, filtering

"open" suppose to take a boolean value and I should be able to do my filter the results with it but I'm ending up with an empty array as result, excuse the messy code please

let queryToMatch = [{$match: {name: project}},{$unwind:"$issues"}];

```
  if(_id != undefined){
    queryToMatch.push({$match: {"_id": _id}})
  }
  if(open != undefined){
    queryToMatch.push({$match: {"open": open}})
  }
  if(issue_title != undefined){
    queryToMatch.push({$match:{"issue_title": issue_title}})
  }
  if(issue_text != undefined){
    queryToMatch.push({$match:{"issue_text": issue_text}})
  }
  if(created_by != undefined){
    queryToMatch.push({$match:{"created_by": created_by}})
  }
  if(assigned_to != undefined){
    queryToMatch.push({$match:{"assigned_to": assigned_to}})
  }
  if(status_text != undefined){
    queryToMatch.push({$match:{"status_text": status_text}})
  }
  console.log(queryToMatch)
  res.json("works")

  Project.aggregate(queryToMatch, (err, data) => {
    //console.log(data)
    res.json(data)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the schema, or sample documents you are attempting to query.  For this reason my answer may not be as you expect.

If I add the following documement...

```
db.test.insert(
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60b44ae6af90ae8f4deca589"),
    "name": "project",
    "open": "open",
    "issue_title": "mytitle",
    "issue_text": "mytext",
    "created_by": "barry",
    "assigned_to": "john",
    "status_text": "mystatus",
    "issues": [
        {
            "issue_type": "type1",
            "issue_date": new Date
        },
        {
            "issue_type": "type2",
            "issue_date": new Date
        },
        {
            "issue_type": "type3",
            "issue_date": new Date
        },
    ]
}
)
```

I can run the following mongo shell commands...

```
var _id = ObjectId("60b44ae6af90ae8f4deca589");
var open = "open";
var issue_title = "mytitle";
var issue_text = "mytext";
var created_by = "barry";
var assigned_to = "john";
var status_text = "mystatus";

let queryToMatch = [{"$match": {"name": "project"}},{$unwind:"$issues"}];

if(_id != undefined){
    queryToMatch.push({$match: {"_id": _id}})
  }
  if(open != undefined){
    queryToMatch.push({$match: {"open": open}})
  }
  if(issue_title != undefined){
    queryToMatch.push({$match:{"issue_title": issue_title}})
  }
  if(issue_text != undefined){
    queryToMatch.push({$match:{"issue_text": issue_text}})
  }
  if(created_by != undefined){
    queryToMatch.push({$match:{"created_by": created_by}})
  }
  if(assigned_to != undefined){
    queryToMatch.push({$match:{"assigned_to": assigned_to}})
  }
  if(status_text != undefined){
    queryToMatch.push({$match:{"status_text": status_text}})
  }
```

... then I can issue the following aggregate statement...

```
db.test.aggregate(queryToMatch).pretty()
```

... and I get the following results...

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60b44ae6af90ae8f4deca589"),
    "name" : "project",
    "open" : "open",
    "issue_title" : "mytitle",
    "issue_text" : "mytext",
    "created_by" : "barry",
    "assigned_to" : "john",
    "status_text" : "mystatus",
    "issues" : {
        "issue_type" : "type1",
        "issue_date" : ISODate("2021-05-31T02:46:04.670Z")
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60b44ae6af90ae8f4deca589"),
    "name" : "project",
    "open" : "open",
    "issue_title" : "mytitle",
    "issue_text" : "mytext",
    "created_by" : "barry",
    "assigned_to" : "john",
    "status_text" : "mystatus",
    "issues" : {
        "issue_type" : "type2",
        "issue_date" : ISODate("2021-05-31T02:46:04.670Z")
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60b44ae6af90ae8f4deca589"),
    "name" : "project",
    "open" : "open",
    "issue_title" : "mytitle",
    "issue_text" : "mytext",
    "created_by" : "barry",
    "assigned_to" : "john",
    "status_text" : "mystatus",
    "issues" : {
        "issue_type" : "type3",
        "issue_date" : ISODate("2021-05-31T02:46:04.670Z")
    }
}
```

It seems your code does work in the context of mongo shell.  My advice is to combine the $match stages together first, then perform the $unwind.  I assume each of the predicates you are tacking on via a `push` are intended to be an 'AND' condition, not an 'OR' condition.  Here is what the end result of your aggregation looks like after all the logical shenanigans...

```
[
    {
        "$match" : {
            "name" : "project"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind" : "$issues"
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60b44ae6af90ae8f4deca589")
        }
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
            "open" : "open"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
            "issue_title" : "mytitle"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
            "issue_text" : "mytext"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
            "created_by" : "barry"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
            "assigned_to" : "john"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
            "status_text" : "mystatus"
        }
    }
]
```

Perhaps this is a cleaner and easier to read query...

```
[
    {
        "$match" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60b44ae6af90ae8f4deca589"),
            "name" : "project",
            "open" : "open",
            "issue_title" : "mytitle",
            "issue_text" : "mytext",
            "created_by" : "barry",
            "assigned_to" : "john",
            "status_text" : "mystatus"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind" : "$issues"
    },
]
```

Consider instead of using `push` you create an object for your $match predicate...

```
var match = new Object();
match.name = "project";

if(_id != undefined){
    match._id = _id;
  }
  if(open != undefined){
    match.open = open;
    
  }
  if(issue_title != undefined){
    match.issue_title = issue_title;
  }
  if(issue_text != undefined){
    match.issue_text = issue_text;
  }
  if(created_by != undefined){
    match.created_by = created_by;
  }
  if(assigned_to != undefined){
    match.assigned_to = assigned_to;
  }
  if(status_text != undefined){
    match.status_text = status_text;
  }
  
  
  
  let queryToMatch = [{"$match": match},{$unwind:"$issues"}];
  db.test.aggregate(queryToMatch).pretty()
```